# When i use the LookAt(target) in unity it works...but the quad is backwards and the player doesn't see it. why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

so I'm working on a game that's 3d but some things are 2d and I need those things to follow the camera so I use this code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowingTextures : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

but the quad rotates backwards and the player doesn't see it. How do I tell unity what is the correct face to show to the player?

Comment: A simple workaround would just be to rotate it by 180 degrees

Comment: it's not working because unity is always showing one face to the player...the wrong one

Comment: Yes, so why can't you just turn it, so the correct face shows?

Comment: because unity always shows that face to the player...doesn't matter how it's in the editor

Answer (score 1):

Try setting position and rotation.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowingTextures : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.LookAt(target.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.forward);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Communist Doggo this is exactly what I proposed...